# ViewModel List was refresh when navigating

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms, cross-platform, prism

I have IListViewModel which handles the list of Id and Name. 
I also have 4 other ViewModel named 
AViewModel , BViewModel , CViewModel , DViewModel and I used Prism framework for Xamarin project

Every time I navigate to another page I added new items in the list.

What I expected is after I navigate in the for Pages I will have 4 items in the list but unfortunately,

Below snippets are my sample code on one of the ViewModel

```
    public class CPageViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private readonly INavigationService _navigationService;
    private readonly IListTestViewModel _listTestViewModel;

    public ICommand NavigateToPreviousCommand => new DelegateCommand(async () => await NavigateToPrevious());
    public ICommand NavigateToRootCommand => new DelegateCommand(async () => await NavigateToRoot());

    public CPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, IListTestViewModel listTestViewModel) : base(navigationService)
    {
        this._navigationService = navigationService;
        this._listTestViewModel = listTestViewModel;

        listTestViewModel.TestListCollection.Add(new MyTestModel { Id = 4, Name = "Josh" });
    }

    private Task NavigateToPrevious()
    {
        return _navigationService.NavigateAsync("BPage");
    }

    private Task NavigateToRoot()
    {
        return _navigationService.GoBackToRootAsync();
    }
}
```

I'm getting 1 record in the List. Below is the sample project file with the problem I encountered

[Click this link to Download my Sample Project](https://ufile.io/n58scz68)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wild guess: `IListTestViewModel` is registered as transient service.

Register as singleton, and you should be fine:

```
containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IListTestViewModel, ListTestViewModelImplementation>();
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response, It saves a lot of my time! Cheers!